# Why is 'Path.startsWith' behaviour different from a 'String.startsWith' operation - even for 'Path.getFilename'

Tags: java, java.nio.file

I am using Java version 1.8.0_31.

I am trying to recursively access a directory tree using the FileVisitor interface.
The program should print the name of all files in `C:/books` whose file name starts with "Ver".
The directory `C:/books` has two files that starts with "Ver", `Version.yxy` and `Version1.txt`.
I tried using `file.getFileName().startsWith("Ver")` but this returns false.

Am I missing something? Here's my code:

```
public class FileVisitorTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        RetriveVersionFiles vFiles = new RetriveVersionFiles();
        try {
            Files.walkFileTree(Paths.get("c:", "books"), vFiles);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
         e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

class RetriveVersionFiles extends SimpleFileVisitor<Path> {

    public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attr) {
        System.out.println(file.getFileName().startsWith("Ver") + " "
              + file.getFileName());
        if (file.getFileName().startsWith("Ver")) {
            //not entering this if block
            System.out.println(file);
        }
        return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
   }
}
```

The output of the above code is:

```
false Version.txt
false Version1.txt
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[`Path.getFileName()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#getFileName--) returns a `Path` containing just the file name.  [`Path.startsWith`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#startsWith-java.lang.String-) checks if the path starts with the same sequence of path components -- a logical, not textual, operation.  The `startsWith` Javadoc is explicit:

> On UNIX for example, the path "foo/bar" starts with "foo" and "foo/bar". It does not start with "f" or "fo".

If you just want to check for textual starts-with-ness, first convert to a String by calling `toString()`: `Path.getFileName().toString().startsWith("Ver")`.

Comment: Thank You, sounds logical and worked too. I actually was referring KathySierra book for java certification, page 515, they gave example as, if ( file.getFileName().endsWith(".class")) Files.delete(file);...and seems its an issue.

Comment: If I designed the API, I wouldn't've added the overload taking a String.  It's too easy to make this mistake.